# Seeking Guidance and Assistance to Secure Clients on Upwork

Tags: freelance-websites, difficult-client, client-support, group-freelancing, freelance

I hope this message finds you well. I am writing to express my current struggles on Upwork and to seek guidance or assistance from experienced freelancers within this community.

For over two months, I have been striving to secure clients and projects on Upwork. I have dedicated considerable time and effort, optimizing my profile, crafting compelling proposals, and investing in connects. Unfortunately, despite my best efforts, I have been facing challenges in securing projects, which has left me feeling quite disheartened and frustrated.

I understand that many freelancers have successfully navigated the intricacies of Upwork and built thriving careers. I am reaching out in the hope that someone might be willing to offer guidance, mentorship, or even the opportunity to collaborate on a project. I am eager to learn and grow as a freelancer and believe that the wisdom and experience of seasoned professionals can be invaluable in achieving this goal.

If you are a freelancer on Upwork who is open to assisting someone who is eager to succeed and willing to put in the work, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Whether it's sharing tips on improving my profile, perfecting proposals, understanding client expectations, or even partnering on a project, any form of support would mean the world to me.

Please feel free to reach out to me directly through Upwork messages, and we can discuss how we can collaborate or connect. I genuinely believe that your guidance could make a significant difference in my freelancing journey.

Thank you for taking the time to read my message. I am looking forward to connecting with experienced freelancers who are willing to help a fellow Upwork member overcome these challenges and pave the way for a successful freelancing career.

Best regards,
Sami,

Comment: You also need to consider the economic situation. Many small businesses are hurting - so much so that they have not been posting projects on Upwork. Secondly, a lot of software developers have been let go from contracts as well as fired. The result is that there are a lot of people chasing few jobs on Upwork. The good news is that a few small businesses are starting to post projects.

Answer (score 1):

The competition on Upwork has increased in the past few years. I am Top Rated on Upwork, and it is challenging even for us to land good projects. Due to the new policy of bidding, it has become even more difficult for beginners to land a project.

I have some suggestions for you:

- Make sure you have a great portfolio. Make side projects in your free time and grow your portfolio.
- Try other platforms too. I would suggest exploring Fiverr as well, as it is really good for beginners. LinkedIn can also be a good platform for landing freelance roles.
- Keep growing your skills, so that when you get an opportunity, you do it with perfection.

Don't lose hope and keep trying. You'll get it!